# rdfa microdata rich snippets and google search results

Tags: rdf, microdata, rich-snippets, rdfa

I take it that stackoverflow discourages consolidating information concerning the same topic, assuming that that will result in sprawling topics... So, here is a clarifying variation on the same question I asked earlier.

I am trying to figure out what exactly google wants in a rich snippet to get a desired result. If I look for examples by searching, I usually see no matching snippet on the page that relates to the search results. Is this because people are submitting the snippets to google, or something else? Is there a path on a website that would usually be where I would find rdfa or microdata that google is using to base search results on?

For example, the goodrelations website mentions "best buy" a lot. If I search for "best buy", the part that is not an ad includes things like "weekly deals". If I look at the source of the web page, I don't see corresponding microdata or rdfa.

If the examples of rich snippets that google gives are what I should use. Why aren't I seeing these being used on web pages?

Comment: Have you tried Google's [structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets)? It will show you what the google search engine sees in a page.

Comment: Yes. Why don't I see that when I look at the web pages I find in search results, then? Also, what you can add using that tool is limited.

Comment: "Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes". My question is not, how do I create a rich snippet. What accounts for the majority of the cases that I find where there is no microdata/rdfa that I find that seems to give information that I see in the search results? Is there a standard place that google is searching?

Comment: AFAIK no, there is no such path. But could you provide concrete examples of this "majority of cases" to sort them out?

Comment: Because goodrelations mentions best buy, several times. If I search for "laptop computer" on google, the result for best buy. If I then go to the actual page, there is no rdf/a and microdata only for an aggregate rating and for "WebPage". In other words, not metadata that would account for the search results. If I search for "home depot", there are a lot of details. Looking at the page, I find no rdf/a or microdata. If I search for "google webmaster tools", there are extra details. If I look at the page, I see no rdf/a or microdata.

Comment: Another example that makes me think that I am missing something: topquadrant's web page is richly marked up with rdfa using goodrelations vocabuluary. If I search for "topquadrant topbraid", none of that information appears in the search results. Most markup is on the "topbraid suite" page. I would think people would search for topbraid composer. Is there a reason that the markup was put there?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you mean is Google Sitelinks.

[image]

This is not controlled with some specific metadata but by Google algorithms itself (and with some simple instrument in Webmaster Tools).

> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to
>   improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster
>   input in the future.

You can find out more about this in Google [specification](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en).

And [here](http://insidesearch.blogspot.ru/2011/08/evolution-of-sitelinks-expanded-and.html) is good blog post from Google that reveals some history behind.

Answer (score 0):

Google has probably just created a custom parsers for Best Buy and other "important" websites. So they can show relevant results. But they would need to keep up with cahnges to site structure, content, media, etc...

Hence there is now a standard so webmasters can supply the information in a structured fashion. Saving Google from doing the work and earning them more money.